# How do you expose and set an internal company website domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

As a project for a company, I'm creating an internal webapp for them to use. I understand how to create the website, but how do I make it so internally it can be accessed at say "internalExample.com"? Currently I plan on having the website stored on an S3 bucket on AWS but it is highly unprofessional to have the S3 bucket endpoint be the url name.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domain name setup with AWS S3 bucket with static hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271678/domain-name-setup-with-aws-s3-bucket-with-static-hosting)

Comment: @TidyDev I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. This question is (I think) around hosting an intranet site on AWS S3, and then limiting access to that intranet site to a particular company network. This is not a factor in the question you linked. I think the question could do with re-tagging as this seems more of a networking question than anything.

Comment: @Stu, you are correct, I would like to host it on an intranet site, but I would like. The question is about how I would create the intranet site in a way that it is accessible through a standard domain. Such as above, "internalExample.com"

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign an S3 bucket hosted site a private website domain, your will need to set a CNAME record pointing to the S3 bucket endpoint.

From [Customizing Amazon S3 URLs with CNAMEs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)

> Depending on your needs, you might not want "s3.amazonaws.com" to
>   appear on your website or service. For example, if you host your
>   website images on Amazon S3, you might prefer
>   http://images.johnsmith.net/ instead of
>   http://johnsmith-images.s3.amazonaws.com/.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but how would I make that CNAME a domain that is available in the intranet of the company. If I wanted to make an internal website with the domain "internalExample.com", where would I start?

Comment: Well the site is not internal. Its hosted on S3.  That is on the public internet. Not sure what you mean by internal in this case.